# How do i combine multiple rows to single row in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, dynamic-sql, dynamic-pivot

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
[Table1ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CreatedByUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Customer] varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Table1ID] ASC
))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table1 on 

insert into table1 ([Table1ID] ,    [CreateDate] ,  [CreatedByUserID] , [Customer] )values(1,GETDATE(),1,'customer1'),(2,GETDATE(),1,'customer1'),(3,GETDATE(),1,'customer1'),(4,GETDATE(),1,'customer1')  

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table1 off  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
[Table2ID]     [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,    
[Table1ID] [int] NOT NULL,  
[ActualData] [nvarchar](255) NULL,  
[BoolCol1] [bit] NOT NULL,  
[IntCol] [int] NULL,    
[BoolCol2] [bit] NULL,  
[BoolCol3] [bit] NOT NULL,  
[BoolCol4] [bit] NOT NULL,  
[BoolCol5] [bit] NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [Table2ID] ASC))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2]  WITH CHECK ADD 
 CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Table2_dbo.Table1_Table1ID] FOREIGN KEY([Table1ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([Table1ID])

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table2 on

insert into table2 
([Table2ID] ,   [Table1ID] ,    [ActualData] ,  [BoolCol1] ,    [IntCol] ,  [BoolCol2] ,    [BoolCol3] ,    [BoolCol4] ,    [BoolCol5] )
values (1,1,'Value 1',1,10,0,1,1,1),(2,1,'Value 2',0,20,1,1,1,0),(3,1,'Value 3',0,30,1,1,1,1),(4,1,'Value 4',0,40,1,1,1,0),(5,1,'Value 5',0,50,1,1,1,1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table2 off
```

similarly i have around 5 tables which need to join and get the data from all columns...can i get a result similar like the below one

```
Table1ID    CreatedDate CreatedByUserID,Customer1       Value1 BoolCol1 Value1 IntCol1  Value1 BoolCol2 Value1 BoolCol3 Value1 BoolCol4 Value1 BoolCol5 Value2 BoolCol1 Value2 IntCol1  Value2 BoolCol2 Value2 BoolCol3 Value2 BoolCol4 Value2 BoolCol5 Value3...   Value3 Int

1   01-01-2015' 1   customer1   1   10  0   1   1   1   0   20  1   1   1   0   0   30
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: Or if you need multiple columns, then here is your duplicate:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: Tab Alleman : The link talks about showing the result of only one column. In my case i have many columns which need to be displayed after PIVOT

Comment: Then see my second comment, it is for a dynamic pivot.

Comment: I don't have your data, so I can't picture what you mean about the one column and other columns.   Can you post an example of the results you are getting from the posted code, and the results you want to get instead?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
 [Table1ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [CreatedByUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Customer] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Table1ID] ASC
))ET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table1 on
insert into table1 
([Table1ID] , [CreateDate] , [CreatedByUserID] , [Customer] )
values(1,GETDATE(),1,'customer1')
,(2,GETDATE(),1,'customer1')
,(3,GETDATE(),1,'customer1')
,(4,GETDATE(),1,'customer1')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table1 off

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
 [Table2ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Table1ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ActualData] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [BoolCol1] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [IntCol] [int] NULL,
 [BoolCol2] [bit] NULL,
 [BoolCol3] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [BoolCol4] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [BoolCol5] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Table2ID] ASC
)
)
GOGO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2]  WITH CHECK ADD 
 CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Table2_dbo.Table1_Table1ID] FOREIGN KEY([Table1ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([Table1ID])SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table2 on

Comment: insert into table2 
([Table2ID] ,
 [Table1ID] ,
 [ActualData] ,
 [BoolCol1] ,
 [IntCol] ,
 [BoolCol2] ,
 [BoolCol3] ,
 [BoolCol4] ,
 [BoolCol5] )
 
 values
 (1,1,'Value 1',1,10,0,1,1,1)
,(2,1,'Value 2',0,20,1,1,1,0)
,(3,1,'Value 3',0,30,1,1,1,1)
,(4,1,'Value 4',0,40,1,1,1,0)
,(5,1,'Value 5',0,50,1,1,1,1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].table2 off

Comment: Table1ID CreatedDate CreatedByUserID,Customer1  Value1 BoolCol1 Value1 IntCol1 Value1 BoolCol2 Value1 BoolCol3 Value1 BoolCol4 Value1 BoolCol5 Value2 BoolCol1 Value2 IntCol1 Value2 BoolCol2 Value2 BoolCol3 Value2 BoolCol4 Value2 BoolCol5 Value3...
                
1 01-01-2015' 1 customer1 1 10 0 1 1 1 0 20 1 1 1 0 0

Comment: first 3 comments has my table script and isert script. ..The last comment is the requeired output.....Similarly i ahve 5 tables to join to get the data and i need data from all these tables.Sorry , i am not able to format the text and it was not accepting many characters. thats why i have many comments..Apologies.....

Comment: We can achieve the same using Pivot in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your only choice is dynamic sql but my recommendation is having a multi rows table and leaving the rest for your server code (AKA ruby,python etc.).

Comment: Thanks for answering..But this will give me multiple record set..I am expecting the result in a single row for a test1id

Comment: what do you mean? if you want to append values in a single column you can do `value1 + value2` for strings

Comment: or `SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2, 'just text') AS new_col FROM table`

Comment: (Imagine Test2 table has values     
Test2ID Test1ID Sectionname FileValidation PostEvent Combined
1 1 Sec1 1 5 1
2 1 Sec2 0 1 1
3 1 Sec3 1 2 1

Comment: Test1ID CustomerName  Sec1FileValidation Sec1PostEvent Sec1Combined Sec2FIleValidation Sec2PostEvent Sec2Combined Sec3Post Sec2Combined Sec3FileValidation
           
1 Cust1  1 5  1 1 1 2 1 1
this is what i am expecting

Comment: Combined output in a single row. This is for reporting purpose.

Comment: Ok. Got you. Is it a limited number of values? Or it's unlimited and the number of columns will be unlimited?

Comment: Unlimited....The number of columns is depend on the number of sectionName .(Not statis)And the risk is i need data from all these columns..I think i need something dynamic

Comment: Thanks Guy, Does it mean that it is not possible through sql

Comment: I don't see a straight forward method for dynamic `join`, and in my opinion, if it's not easy, you probably shouldn't do it or do it differently. this is why i recommend it to be on the server code and not in the SQL query.